# How should I configure Redis for Django Channels 2.0?

Tags: python, django, redis, django-channels

I'm getting an error sometimes when I run a Worker of Django Channels as Background Task. The task consumes an open third-party WebSocket with a library called Pysher, processes that data, and then sends the resulting data through the Channel Layer to a group of Websockets listening to our application using Redis (the Message Broker).

I know that the problem does not have to do with the Pysher library, since if I comment the code to send the message through the Channel Layer runs whitout problems. The problem occurs due to the sending of the message in the Channel Layer and only happens sometimes, many times the sending occurs successfully and other times it throws the error, the last behaviour makes me think that it may have to do with Redis or the Channel Layer and its configuration or something like that, maybe Redis is reaching some limit.

**Error message**

```
error from callback bound method Connection._on_message of Connection(Thread-2, started daemon 140614612023040):
[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

SO and Redis version: Ubuntu 16 + Redis 3.2

Pip Dependencies

```
aiodns==1.1.1
aiohttp==2.3.10
aioredis==1.0.0
amqp==2.2.2
asgiref==2.1.6
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==1.6.1
async-timeout==2.0.0
attrs==17.4.0
autobahn==17.10.1
Automat==0.6.0
Babel==2.5.3
billiard==3.5.0.3
biopython==1.69
cchardet==2.1.1
celery==4.1.0
certifi==2018.1.18
cffi==1.11.4
channels==2.0.2
channels-redis==2.1.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.1.4
daphne==2.0.4
dash==0.21.0
dash-core-components==0.21.1
dash-html-components==0.9.0
dash-renderer==0.11.3
decorator==4.2.1
Django==2.0.2
django-celery-beat==1.1.1
django-celery-results==1.0.1
django-mysql==2.2.0
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Caching==1.4.0
Flask-Compress==1.4.0
flower==0.9.2
future==0.16.0
hiredis==0.2.0
hyperlink==17.3.1
idna==2.6
idna-ssl==1.0.0
incremental==17.5.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort==4.3.4
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
kombu==4.1.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==1.0
mccabe==0.6.1
msgpack==0.5.6
multidict==4.1.0
mysqlclient==1.3.12
nbformat==4.4.0
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.4
numpy==1.13.3
oauthlib==2.0.7
pandas==0.22.0
plotly==2.5.1
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pycares==2.3.0
pycparser==2.18
pylint==1.8.2
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
Pysher==0.3.0
PySocks==1.6.8
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-telegram-bot==10.0.1
python-twitter==3.4.1
pytz==2018.3
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
service-identity==17.0.0
six==1.11.0
tornado==4.5.3
traitlets==4.3.2
Twisted==17.9.0
txaio==2.8.2
urllib3==1.22
vine==1.1.4
websocket-client==0.47.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wrapt==1.10.11
yarl==1.1.0
zope.interface==4.4.3
```

Channel Layer configuration

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)]
        },
    },
}
```

My code

```
# Synconsumer Class that runs as Channels Worker Background task
class BTWorker(SyncConsumer):

    # Class method
    def get_data(self, event):

        # Callback function that runs every time We receive a message from the thrid party Websocket
        def callback(*args, **kwargs):
            # Data processing
            raw_dict = json.loads(args[0])
            var_dict = {
                'id': raw_dict['id'],
                'other_key': other_value
            }
            var_list = [var_dict]

            # Send data via Channel Layer and Redis (CODE that generate the ISSUE!!)
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                "group_name",
                {
                    "type": "some.type",
                    "text": json.dumps(trade_uni_list)
                }
            )

        # Websocket Third party connection handler
        def connect_handler(data):
            channel = pusher.subscribe('token')
            channel.bind('channel', callback)

        # Websocket Third Party connection via Pysher Library
        pusher = pysher.Pusher('******some_key****')
        pusher.connection.bind('pusher:connection_established', connect_handler)
        pusher.connect()
```

Comment: Sounds like you have another instance running on the same network address.

Comment: If you turn debugging logs, its probably because everytime `self.channel_layer.group_send` is called, it sets a key in redis. That needs a port to open on your local machine. If you are opening more connections than your OS allows, you get this error. Try increasing that limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this sounds ridiculous, given that it works sometimes, but can you switch 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' and see if that fixes? I'm seeing that certain python modules may be confused by localhost... even though it works intermittently.